# Codeigniter database not showing in view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, controller

I am learning CI and I'm trying to do this tutorial where you fetch data. My browser is just dumping this and nothing else

> {entries}
> {id}

{title}
{news}

{/entries}

Can you please help me figure this out? I'm pretty sure it has to do with my parser in the controller file

now this is my view:

```
<head>
<title>News Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
       {entries}
           <p>{id}</p>
           <h3>{title}</h3>
           <p>{news}</p>
       {/entries}
</body>
```

Model

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class NewsModel extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
    $this->load->database();
        
    }
    
    public function getNews($slug = FALSE){
            $query = $this->db->get('news');
            return $query->result_array();

    }
    
}
```

and controller

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        

        $this->load->model('newsModel');
    }

    public function index() {
   
        $news = $this->NewsModel->getNews();

// I believe the issue is in the next few lines

        $data['contactjs']=$this->parser->parse('templates/Javascript/contactjs',[],TRUE);
        $data['bootCSS']=$this->parser->parse('templates/CSS/bootCSS',[],TRUE);
        $data['CSS']=$this->parser->parse('templates/CSS/CSS',[],TRUE);
        $data['jQuery']=$this->parser->parse('templates/Javascript/jQuery',[],TRUE);
        $data['bootstrap']=$this->parser->parse('templates/Javascript/bootstrap',[],TRUE);



         $template = '{id} {title} {news}';
         $newsData = array('entries'=> $news);
         $newsData = $this->parser->parse('pages/news', [], TRUE);
         $data['news'] = $this->parser->parse('pages/news', $news, TRUE);
        
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/news');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this right? $this->load->model('newssModel'); You should have got an error displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the parser library? Try to output the $news variable, see if it contains some data. Also, check your application/log folder for more information. Maby there is a php error you're not seeing.

Next line of code should load your pages/news view just like any other view without the parser:

```
$this->load->view('pages/news'); // This view doesn't contain any parsed data now
```

I think you should create a temp variable and place all the data of all parsed views into it. Then load it in a view. To check, try to output the last variable and see if it contains any data like so;

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($data['news']);
```